# Rename file by removing repetitive substrings contained in filenames

Tags: bash, rename, string

I need to rename a bunch of files with the following pattern:

```
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_bold.json
```

to

```
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_bold.json
```

Each filename only contains one type of substring out of 4 possibilities - `run-01_` (or `run-02_`, `run-03_`, `run-04`)

Note that the substring `run-0[1-4]_`  can repeat itself random amount of times in a given file.

I am out of my wits and the closest thing I can find is [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336310/linux-batch-rename-files). However, based on my limited knowledge in string manipulation, I would love to have more help!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what we should remove. Do we look for the specific string `_run-01`? Can we also have `run-02`? Other strings? The more detail you give us, the better we will be able to help you.

Comment: Hey @terdon thanks for your comment!! Edits added and let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer. One more thing though, please tell us (edit it into your question) what operating system you are using and, if Linux, which one. That will help us know what tools you have available.

Answer (score 1):

Or perl:

```bsh
$ f=sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_bold.json
$ g=$(perl -pe 's/(_run-0[1-4])\1+/$1/' <<< "$f")
$ echo "$g"
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_bold.json
```

---

with the perl-flavoured `rename(1)` program:

```bsh
$ touch "$f"
$ ls sub*json
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_run-01_bold.json
$ rename 's/(_run-0[1-4])\1+/$1/' sub*json
$ ls sub*json
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_bold.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If things get more complicated than `rename` can handle directly, I tend to just write a short script with basically the same pattern

```
for file in *.json
do
   changedname="$(echo "$file" | sed 's/regex/replacement/flags')"
   mv -- "$file" "$changedname"
done
```

in your case, you're looking for the string `run-0[1-4]_`, and would replace it with the empty string ``, and your flags would include `g` for "do this as many times it takes until you reach the end of line", so

```
sed 's/run-0[1-4]_//g'
```

is what you're aiming for.

If the first occurrence is not to be removed, then that's not hard, either!

```
sed -e 's/\(run-0[1-4]_.*\)run-0[1-4]_/\1/g'
```

Comment: My understanding is that the first occurrence should not be removed.

Comment: @Ned64 ah, well, fixed that.

Comment: I'm testing and it's not giving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bsh
for i in *.json; do
  a="${i##*_run}"
  b="${i%%_run*}"
  n="$b""_run$a"
  # mv -- "$i" "$n"
  printf "%s" "$n"
done
sub-2795479_ses-V1_task-rest_acq-REST1_dir-AP_run-01_bold.json
```

For renaming then:

```bsh
mv -- "$i" "$n"
```

---

Note: do backups of the files when performing remove/moving operations.